# Is the word "submillimeter" an adjective?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

Is this sentence correct? It sounds weird:

> The accuracy is sub-millimeter.

Is it OK to use "submillimeter" without the "-"?

Comment: The OP is right; his sentence does sound weird. I would say: "The spot was located to sub-millimeter accuracy." (As for the hyphen, I don't know.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is indeed an adjective.

This is the definition given by Dictionary.com:

> **submillimeter** *adjective*
>
> less than a millimeter in size

(Spelt "submillimet**re**" in Australia and the UK)

Judging by a quick Google search, "submillimeter" should not be spelt with a hyphen.

Answer (score 1):

I think in general usage no hyphen is required. But in some contexts, the hyphen might draw attention to the small scale and emphasise it.

"With a microscope you can easily see the sub-millimeter scales of a butterfly's wing"